# How do i draw a full Webpage using Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, html, jeditorpane

i tried to draw a full webpage in Java Swing, but it looks awful. What does it need to look like in Chrome or some other explorer?

It looks like this:
[image]
[image]
and not like a normal video on youtube.
Source:

```
    JEditorPane jep = new JEditorPane();
    jep.setEditable(false);   

    try {
      jep.setPage("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EcdbEax46bA");
    }catch (IOException e) {
      jep.setContentType("text/html");
      jep.setText("<html>Could not load</html>");
    } 

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jep);     
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Test HTML");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
    f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
    f.setVisible(true);
```

So what do i need to view a full webpage?

Comment: Swings HTML/css support is limited (HTML 3 ), you’d better exploring JavaFX

Comment: Use the `Desktop` class to display the webpage in the default browser of your computer. See [How to Integrate With the Desktop Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html).